# Select fields from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, select

I want to make a query a little complicated, and I'm not able to do it alone.

I have the following tables:

```
Table color:
id_uo  P
id_cor   PF 
id_area   F 
text_cor

Table area:  
id_area  P
text_area

Table atv:   
id_dest PF
id_cor PF
id_uo PF

Table dest:  
id_dest P
type
```

What I intend to have as a result is a table that returns the fields as follows:

```
text_area | id_cor | text_cor | type
```

Do not know if atv through the table, I can create a query that helps me access to all parameters. Sorry but I'm newbie in the creation of more complex query. I've already tried that with Join and Union but got nothing that I would get. Can you help me?

```
select * from area:

id_area | text_area
--------------------
  1     |   info1 
  2     |   info2

select * from color:

id_cor |  id_uo | id_area |text_cor
-----------------------------------
  1    |  1222  |    1    |  create
  2    |    1   |    2    |  teste
  2    |  1222  |    1    |  sssss

select * from dest:

id_dest | type
--------------
   1    |   E
   2    |   M

select * from atv:

id_dest | id_cor | id_uo
----------------------------
  1     |   2    |  1222
  2     |   2    |   1
  2     |   1    |  1222
```

What I want to achieve for each id_uo is the following result (for id_uo: 1222):

```
text_area | id_cor | text_cor | type
-------------------------------------
 info1    | 1      |  create  |   M
 info1    | 2      |  sssss   |   E
```

Comment: Could you show us a few rows of sample data and the desired output?  And possibly the query you have so far.  With these you could be more sure that you'd get the answer you want.

Comment: hope you explained everything to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the result that you want by using a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) on each of the tables.

```
select a."text_area",
  c."id_cor",
  c."text_cor",
  d."type"
from area a
left join color c
  on a."id_area" = c."id_area"
left join atv t
  on c."id_cor" = t."id_cor"
  and c."id_uo" = t."id_uo"
left join dest d
  on t."id_dest" = d."id_dest"
where t."id_uo" = 1222
order by c."id_cor"
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa1a8/4)

Result:

```
| TEXT_AREA | ID_COR | TEXT_COR | TYPE |
----------------------------------------
|     info1 |      1 |   create |    M |
|     info1 |      2 |    sssss |    E |
```

You will see that when I used the `LEFT JOIN` on the `atv` table, I joined it to the `color` table on both `id_cor` and `id_uo`.

Comment: Exactly, what has walked laps here and never did the query that way. thank you very much